# NodeJs Store Json from multiple requests to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, request, each

I am working on a crawler that stores the retrieved and parsed data into my MySQL DB.
Storing the results works pretty well, but I am stuck when it comes to end the connection.

I am using `request`, `cheerio`, `async` and `mysql`:

```
// DB params
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "mydatabase",
});

// Open connection to DB
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});

// Array of Cities to crawl
var cities = ["olten", "zurich"];

// Todays Date 
var today = new Date();
...
today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;

// Search every city
async.each(cities, function(item, callback){    
        // The Page to crawl
        var page = "https://www.thepageto.com/search_xhr?fn=" + /*cities[i]*/ item + "&tn=&db=" + today + "&sort=trip_date&order";
        console.log("Visiting page " + page);
        request(page, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {console.log("Error: " + error);}
            // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
            console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                // Parse JSON
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                // Use only result > html code
                var content = data.html.results;                
                // Parse html
                var $ = cheerio.load(content);
                // Iterate through offers & Extract information & Store in a Object
                $('.trip.relative').each(function() {
                    // Empty Object, has the same structure as the Db table
                    var json = {id: "", driver: "", rating: "", date: "", time: "", start: "", stops: "", end: "", price: "", url: "", query: ""};
                    // Assigning values
                    json.driver = $(this).find('.username').text();
                        ...  
                    // Save filled object in Db
                    save(json, callback);
                });         
            }
        });
  }, function(err){ 
        if (err) {
            console.log('could not save');
        } else {
            console.log('lets end connection');
            con.end(function(err) {if (err) throw err;});
        }
  }
);

function save(item, callback) {
   con.query('INSERT INTO offers SET ?', item, callback); 
}
```

The problem is, that the DB connection is ended before anything could be stored into the DB. The `con.end()` is always fired before the actual query or before the query completed. I have the intension that the save function has to return something when its done. If i run the script without the `con.end()`, the data is stored into the DB perfectly.
I am new to Node so I am still learning and hopefully you can help me with this.

**Edit:** 
I now get an:

```
ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    at save (/home/juki/crawler/crawler.js:143:46)
```

As well as an:

```
Error: Callback was already called.
    at Query._callback (/home/juki/crawler/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:839:                                                                                                                     36)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not call `callback` from your crawler.

You also do not seem to wait for save to finish. Try to rework `save` function, so it takes callback too. Something like:

```
function save(item, callback) {
    con.query('INSERT INTO offers SET ?', item, callback); 
}
```

And then call it like:

```
save(json, callback);
```

where `callback` is the one you get from `async.each`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where do i have to place the `save(json, callback)` then? And where do i have to callback from the crawler?

Comment: Replace `save(json)` in your current example with `save(json, callback)`. That should do it. Also check `async.each` documentation at https://github.com/caolan/async#eachcoll-iteratee-callback - their example with file saving is really very similar to your situation (you just save to database instead of directly to some file).

Comment: Unfortunately this works only for the first iteration of `async.each`. Afterwards I get an `Error: Callback was already called.` Any ideas?

Comment: Please update your code, so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Code is updated. As you can see, `callback` from `save()` is undefined and I get an error that `callback` was already called on `async.each`. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that all the code there is? Because if that is all, then there is no other place where callback is called. How does line 143 look?